# In the X.509 CRL v2 format, why is there a requirement to duplicate the "AlgorithmIdentifier" fields?

Tags: x509certificate, x509, pki, rfc, certificate-revocation

After looking through the X.509 CRL baseline format version 2, I have some questions.

In each TBSCertList, why is the "signature" tag named "signature" when it is not the actual signature but rather only the algorithm identifier... and further, why is said algorithm identifier tag required when the actual signature is not present? See attached screenshot from the RFC showing this as so.

Also, why is the algorithm identifier required for each TBSCertList when the whole CertificateList is signed instead? And further, the RFC says that both the "signatureAlgorithm" tag in CertificateList must exactly match the "signature" tag in TBSCertList - why is this so? Isn't this a bit redundant or is there a specific reason?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Potential (cross-site) duplicates: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/114746/why-is-the-signature-algorithm-listed-twice-in-an-x509-certificate or https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24788/signaturealgorithm-vs-tbscertificate-signature

Comment: @TylerH there is more than one question asked in this question, and that additional question is not a duplicate

Comment: You should edit your question to focus on one question--asking multiple questions in a single post is not allowed on Stack Overflow. That aside, my point in posting the previous comment was not to try and close this question, just point you in the right direction; you can't close questions as dupes of ones on other network sites, unfortunately.

Comment: It's clearly not a programming question, and so it *is* off-topic on Stack Overflow. That said, yes, it's redundant and worthless, and thus confusing. I'm a big critic of IETF standards, particularly security and crypto standards, so this just triggers me.